# CentOS 6 : Group descriptors corrupted

Tags: linux, centos

I found the following in dmesg and I am wondering what I can do to fix it: `EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): group descriptors corrupted!`.

Will I need to take the server offline in order to recover the file system or is it possible to do it without taking the server offline?

```
EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 128 failed (22619!=896)
EXT4-fs (snumbd1d): group descriptors corrupted!
snumbd_open_blk(blkid,65537): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbdctl_release(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
snumbdctl_open(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
session_init(mms,223881): OK. kdev=fc:1, len=16351232 sect=512 s=ffff88001f1ea000 pgrp=(210331).
snumbd_open_blk(blkid,65545): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbd_open_blk(udisks-part-id,65546): Disable access (515,210331,210331)...
snumbdctl_release(mms,223881): OK s=ffff88001f1ea000
```

Comment: I'm not sure this needs to be [cross posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717770/centos-6-group-descriptors-corrupted).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717770/centos-6-group-descriptors-corrupted

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how you are using corrupted file system, you may need to run `fsck` to fix these error and for that you need to unmount the related mount point.

So you don't have to take complete system offline until issue is with `/` mount point (Or OS filesystem related).